# SOQL query in Trigger returns no results but returns a row in Developer Console

Tags: soql, contentdocumentlink

I have the following code snippet in a Helper class that's being called by an After Insert trigger (modified to demonstrate my objective):

```
Set<Id> reuseIds = new Set<Id>();
reuseIds.add('a0g0R000001VnjMQAS');

List<ContentDocumentLink> allLinks = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :reuseIds];
System.debug('allLinks.size() ' + allLinks.size());
```

The debug output is showing me that I'm getting zero results. However, when I run the same query in the debug console, I see the single row returned that I'm expecting.

I have included **without sharing** on the trigger Helper class even though my understanding is that's not necessary in a trigger, but it doesn't change my results.

Can anyone offer any clues as to what I may be experiencing here?

[image]

Comment: What object is the trigger on?

Comment: The trigger is on a custom object.

Comment: You are saying that you execute this SOQL on a helper class from an after insert trigger. The ContentDocumentLink "Represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file and where it's shared." You probably don't have any ContentDocumentLink related to the new inserted record?

Comment: That's a good thought, but it's there. It's an After Insert trigger on another object, related to an existing one (the LinkedEntityId). And I can query in Developer Console before the trigger is executed and the record comes back -- just not in code for some reason.

Comment: what's the ShareType value in the row returned in the query in dev console?

Comment: Is your trigger helper “with sharing”?

Comment: What user are you running as when you test it via the trigger? If it's a community or guest user, then files are hidden even "without sharing" unless they are explicitly shared. I imagine (but don't know for sure) that this applies to ContentDocumentLink, too.

Comment: The ShareType is 'V'. Regarding the running user, it is a Community user, but I have the code implemented in a class "without sharing." I see what you're saying though about "with sharing" and that definitely seems like a tough problem for me.